# Replace all occurrences of item in sublists within list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I would like to replace all occurrences of a string within a list composed of strings and sublists, so something like this:

```
myarray = ['Hello', 'how', 'how', ['are', 'what', 'how'], 'you', 'how']
```

would be changed to this:

```
myarray = ['Hello', 'X', 'X', ['are', 'what', 'X'], 'you', 'X']
```

Thus far I've only been able to replace the instances of 'how' that are strings and NOT within sublists. Here's the code I have currently:

```
myarray = ['Hello', 'how', 'how', ['are', 'what', 'how'], 'you', 'how']
for n, i in enumerate(myarray):
    for sublist in myarray:
        if i == 'how':
            myarray[n]="X"
print myarray
```

and here's its output:

```
['Hello', 'X', 'X', ['are', 'what', 'how'], 'you', 'X']
```

Any ideas how I might fix this?

Comment: +1 for asking a clear first question + own attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write a recursive function for that.

```
def nestrepl(lst, what, repl):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            nestrepl(item, what, repl)
        else:
            if item == what:
                lst[index] = repl
```

Demo:

```
>> nestrepl(myarray, 'how', 'X')
>> myarray
['Hello', 'X', 'X', ['are', 'what', 'X'], 'you', 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although type checking isn't generally approved of in Python, it's necessary to handle recursive data structures like this where elements of the original list can be data points or sublists. The trick is to handle them with a recursive function.

```
myarray = ['Hello', 'how', 'how', ['are', 'what', 'how'], 'you', 'how']

def subst(lst, val, rep):
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) == list:
            result.append(subst(item, val, rep))
        elif item == val:
            result.append(rep)
        else:
            result.append(item)
    return result

print(subst(myarray, "how", "X"))
```

gives you the output you want.

You could, as in @timgeb's answer, replace the items in place if you want - I formulated my answer this way in case the original list was required, but if not then replacement will probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a imported solution, so like the above writers I would write a higher-order recursive function:

```
def full_replace(array, string):
    new_array = []
    if isinstance(array, str):
        return 'X' if array == string else string
    else:
        for n in array:
        new_array.append(full_replace(n, string))
    return new_array
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use a recursive function to solve this problem!

```
def replace(item_want_to_replace, replacement, list_input):
    for sublist in list_input:
        if type(sublist) == list:
            list_input = replace(item_want_to_replace, replacement, sublist)
        else:
            if sublist == item_want_to_replace:
                sublist = replacement
    return list_input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myarray = ['Hello', 'how', 'how', ['are', 'what', 'how'], 'you', 'how']
    new_array = replace('how', 'X', myarray)
    print(new_array)
```

So here is the explanation for my code: I create a function that get 3 variables ***item_want_to_replace***, and ***replacement*** as strings and ***list_input*** as list or nested list. Then, I use *for* loop to scan ***list_input*** and check if the type of each sublist is a list or not. If the sublist is a list, I assign ***list_input*** a new value since we will need to change the value inside that list also; thus, I call the function again (recursion method as it goes over and over again if there is a list inside a list) and ***list_input*** will have a new fixed value that is already changed *'how'* into 'X' in the list inside your current list. After that, the *else* statement is just simply used to check the condition whether the sublist is the same with ***item_want_to_replace*** (which is *'how'* in this situation). Then, it will assign sublist as ***replacement*** and return ***list_input*** to apply recursion as I mentioned above!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need recursion:

```
for ind,elem in enumerate(myarray[:]):
    if isinstance(elem,list):
        for sub_ind,sub_elem in enumerate(elem):
            if sub_elem =="how":
                myarray[ind][sub_ind] = "X"
    elif elem == "how":
        myarray[ind] = "X"

In [4]: myarray
Out[4]: ['Hello', 'X', 'X', ['are', 'what', 'X'], 'you', 'X']
```

Comment: If you're willing to give up support for arbitrary levels of nesting, that is.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien the question is to replace items in a list and sublists not sublists of sublists.